# SAP CAP Install Plugin Multiapps Error. Why?

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-foundry, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cap

I want to deploy a CAP project to BTP Cloud Foundry with `cf deploy`. However, I get the error:

> "deploy" is not a registered command. See "cf help -a".

So I installed the Multiapps plugin in order to solve the problem.
https://github.com/cloudfoundry/multiapps-cli-plugin/blob/master/README.md

Now I get this error, when I run "cf install-plugin multiapps -f":

> dial tcp 127.0.0.1:55463: socket: An invalid argument was supplied.
> exit status 1
> File is not a valid cf CLI plugin binary.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the Environment-Variable `CF_PLUGIN_HOME` to `C:\` on your system. Then it should work.

Kind Regards,
Georg

Comment: Hi Georg, I also stuck at the very same place as Sebastian (I am using Mac M2). I would also like to update the CF_PLUGIN_HOME, as you have suggested. However, as far as I see, the required .cf/plugins folder is already -successfully- generated under the path of ~/Users/<myuser>/. So do you think still I need to update this variable, or my problem could be something else??

Thanks in advance, Merve

Comment: Hi Merve, unfortunately I have no experience with this topic on Macs, especially not on M1/M2 based ones. I am sorry but i cannot help you with that.

Comment: Hi Georg, thanks for the comment anyway. I have raised a github issue to the team, looking forward to hear from them.

Comment: Mac M2 multiapps plugin installation issue is resolved after installing xcode-select (command: xcode-select --install). Sharing as a reference.